# Why does renaming Task List not display %20?

Tags: task-list

Here is a question about naming conventions for SharePoint 2013 and the Task Lists.

When I name a Task List "This_Task_List" and save I don't get the %20 in the URL for because of the naming conventions. When I go into the edit List section and take out the underscores the spaces are there and yet there are not %20 in the URL. Why is that?

Yet, when I have spaces "This Task List" the %20 are displayed in Task's URL. However, when I rename the Task List as "This_Task_List" the %20 remain.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the first name you assign becomes the **internal name** and the (same) **display name**

The URL is built from the **internal name**

If you rename a List (or Page or Field or ContentType) you rename the **display name**, the **internal name** is NOT changed

General advice when creating SharePoint items (lowercase i): List, Field, ContentType is never to use spaces (for creating the Internal Name)

Create them from a programmers POV (CamelCase or _ notation), then rename them for the UX part (displayname)

When you start working with Code on SharePoint you will almost always use **internal names**

Comment: So use CamelCase or _notation. Rename them in the UX part display name. Got it.  However, I can name my Task Items with spaces, correct?

Comment: That is **content**  of Title (Task Name) field, you can put whatever you want in there

Answer (score 1):

Because in SharePoint once when you created list or list column `first time` it will create the `unique` `internal name`. 
That **internal name of the list or list column can't be change after creation** while you can change the `display name`.

You are changing the `display name`, but `internal name` will remains as it is. It can't be change. So when you first create with name `This Task List` it will create internal name with `%20` but when you change display name it to `This_Task_List` the internal name won't be change.

Read more : [Static Name vs. Internal Name vs. Display Name in SharePoint](http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2009/04/static-name-vs-internal-name-vs-display-name-in-sharepoint/)